# Activity and view setup of Android app - should I create new activities for each page?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

I'm working on an Android app that will look like this (Photoshop mockup):

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/873a7d8a6832be9a4f8363f90c0a1a98.png))</sub>

The bar at the top will always be at the top and the view below that will always be the "header" of the content. Should I just load new views inside the ScrollView below the header or create entire new activities for each page so that the back button is supported better? And how would that work? Currently the main activity builds the above layout with a custom view for the header, top bar and content.

Comment: @Overv. Have you looked into `ListView`.  You can supply multiple header views and use an array or database cursor to supply the data for the list.

Comment: A listview will be overkill if your data is static

Comment: @Falmarri That depends on how many items there are.  If there are enough items where you need to scroll, then it still makes sense.

Comment: @Mayra: No it doesn't. You should use a scrollview if it needs to scroll. Why would you bother with the overhead and complexities of an adapter if you can just add rows in xml

Comment: @Mayra: Ok granted, if it's a ton of items. I was thinking more on this specific example.

Comment: @falmarri.  has he said the data is static. no.  look at what he has put in the picture of what he wants to do.  do you think it will be static?  if you do... lol

Comment: @sugar: yes it does look static. Unless he's going to be dynamically adding forums or something.

Comment: @falmarri. lol you miss the point.  the data he his displaying and the data he will display in the future changes. but hey you have 7k+ points everything you say must be right ;P.

Comment: @sugar: You don't need to be so defensive... The VIEW is static. The only thing I see possibly changing is the number of subforums. That's all easily updated. The point of a listview is to have a dynamic number of views.

Comment: @falmarri.  deflect all you like you still miss my point.

/sugarynugs Hammers Head To No Avail.

peace ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I just load new views inside
>   the ScrollView below the header or
>   create entire new activities for each
>   page

We can't answer for sure, but you will most likely want to create new activities for each page.

Just include the header in your new activities as well. Google has a good example here http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Comment: to me it looks like some feed reader so a new activity for each item is way overkill...

Comment: @sugarynugs That doesn't necessarily mean a new class type for each item, they could all lead to a particular instance of the same activity.  Its still going to be easier to manage lifecycle, etc. with multiple activities.

Comment: @mayra.  Falmarri's a bit touchy today pmsl.  I look at what he has put in his picture and read his question.  My take is he is either going to show another list or a webview.  If it's another list then why not just change the adapter and if its a webview, you could fire up another activity to show the webview for that item and destroy on back button.

Comment: @sugarynugs Even though I agree with your opinion on the ListView, lets try to avoid the personal attacks.. Personally I would find messing around with the adapter a lot more complicated to maintain than just opening another activity.  As I said, it could be another instance of the same activity, but that way navigation like back is already handled for you.  In my experience this has been easiest to deal with each view as a different activity.  The overhead is not that much.

Comment: @mayra.  Please that wasn't a personal attack.  Just an observation.  The question is what Overv wants to do with an onClick of one of his items, when we know that the best answer can be supplied.

@falmarri.  Apologies if I am personally attacking you.